# Word or phrase to stress the importance of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How to stress the importance of something regarding a recent example? Clearly (in an essay) I want to stress the importance of a well-known scientific topic by pointing out to a recent news, namely granting one million dollars to a project in the field. In fact, I want something to convey this message:

> This is an important field and the recent news could be considered another piece of notable evidence.

So, what’s the word or phrase to best do so?

Comment: I wish to be emphatic ...
I must emphasize ...
Most importantly ... 
Without hesitation ...
Without a doubt ...
I can't stress enough ...
... and so on

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "Important!!".

Answer (score 2):

You can use *[imperative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/imperative)*

**imperative**(adjective)

> absolutely necessary or required; unavoidable

[dictionary.com]

*Usage* (according to your example)

> Considering the recent grant that the project has received, it is **imperative** that we take this field seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Since it’s your essay I think you can and should simply avoid “hedging” the importance of the evidence and replace “could be considered” with “is” to help achieve the emphasis you’re after (and you could even consider throwing in “fact”):

> This is an important field and the recent news **is** clear/further
>   evidence of this [fact].

If you want to maintain a slight bit of hedging for humility’s sake and avoid “stating facts,” you could consider the following:

> This is an important field, as is evidenced/shown by the recent news.

or

> The importance [and renewed/continued/increasing relevance] of this
>   field is [clearly/further] evidenced/shown by the recent
>   announcement/news [of the grant/of the awarding of the grant].

Or to put a bit more emphasis on the importance of the “news” (and make the voice a bit more active) you could flip the word order:

> The recent announcement/news of the [awarding of the] grant is
>   [clear/further] evidence of the importance/relevance of this field.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ***[emphasise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/emphasize)*** or *highlight*:

> - To give emphasis to; stress: *She emphasized that the matter was urgent.*
> - To cause to appear important or deserving of attention: *The bank failure emphasized the need for reform.*

(AHD)

Answer (score -1):

Trying to be as concise as possible, you may say:

**We need to focus on this hot scientific topic**.

Comment: Here, it is better to use the word 'active' instead of 'hot'.